# jQuery scroll to bottom of page locks/stutters/judders scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of my page after the user submits a form. However, when I execute the following code, the browser scrolls to the bottom of the page, but will not allow me to scroll back up (via mousewheel, scrollbar, or arrow press) without locking/shuttering/juddering.

```
var scrollToBottom = function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()}, 0);
}
```

Any idea what's causing this? It seems to "relax" its grip on the browser after about five seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your function and it did not lock me at the bottom for 5 seconds. By default it will lock when scrolling and release you when the browser reaches the predetermined location.

http://jsfiddle.net/oq9eo2zz/2/

Something else is likely causing the issue, but if you're looking for a quick work around you could force it to unlock (stop animating) on 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll keyup keydown'.

```
$(window).on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll keyup keydown", function(e){
  $('html, body').stop();
});
```

0 duration:
http://jsfiddle.net/oq9eo2zz/1/

3000 duration:
http://jsfiddle.net/oq9eo2zz/4/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
var scrollToBottom = function() {
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
  return false;
}
```

OR

```
function scrollToBottom()
{
  alert("Scrolling to bottom ...");
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```